# Странности работы json_encode

Tags: json, php

Есть код:

```
 1. var_dump($arr); die(); // Выводит массив 
 2. echo json_encode($arr);
    die(); //

1) Выводит:
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      string(249) "<li><div class="photo"><a href="/russia/object/3028"><img src="/russia/images/previews//223.jpg"></a></div><a class="price" href="/russia/object/3028">����������� ���.</a>
                            <div>Метро: <span>������</span></div>"
```

2) Выводит: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Не пойму - из-за чего Json_encode губит весь массив?

Comment: Возможно, проблемы в кодировке.
Пробуйте записывать в массив разные строчки и смотреть на результат. Я бы записал сначала в $arr пару-тройку строк, состоящих из a-zA-Z0-9, и, если все с этими данными работает как надо - попробовал бы разные кодировки этих строк.
Я несколько раз сталкивался с такой бедой, и, насколько помню, дело решалось кастомным json_encode (нашел где-то в комментариях к документации json_encode), или же изменением кодировки.

Comment: если вы кодируете данные в жсон, то в агенте приема следует правильно раскодировать его. и вообще, покажите весь код, телепаты все в отпусках

Comment: Да - сформировал другой массив - он нормально сериализовался. Значит дело в кодировке. Что можете по кодировке сказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По кодировке - [читайте учебники](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php), все уже сказано:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: @deivan, насколько я понял, у автора такой вывод в буквальном смысле:

    Выводит: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

Comment: ну он же в последнем комментарии про кодировку спросил, вот  и ответ на это

Comment: @deivan, ну хватит уже. Автор совсем про другое.